# How do i use SVG.js plugins in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, svg, svg.js

I am using `svg.js` in my Laravel project running `vue.js`.

This is how i use `svg.js`

**Step 1:** Install `svg.js` as a plugin in my vue app.

```
import svgJs from "svg.js/dist/svg"

export default {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.prototype.$svg = svgJs
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Import and use the plugin.

```
import svgJs from "./plugins/vueSvgPlugin"

Vue.use(svgJs);
```

**Step 3:** Then i can do this.

```
console.log(this.$svg);

console.log(this.$svg.get("samplesvg"));
```

However i am not sure how to add the `svg.js` plugins. I want to use below three plugins, in case someone wants to know.

1. svg.select.js
2. svg.resize.js
3. svg.draggable.js

Comment: Make SVG a global and import them. That should work

Comment: select.js and resize.js don't have definition files for an import

Comment: Aren't files without an export just executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my approach according to comment by [Fuzzyma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588400/how-do-i-use-svg-js-plugins-in-vue-js#comment97874178_55588400)

So i just did simple import in my app file, and it all worked fine. It is also worth mentioning that i used versions `< 3.0` to make it work.

```
import * as SVG from 'svg.js/dist/svg';
import './plugins/svg.draggable/dist/svg.draggable';
import './plugins/svg.select/dist/svg.select';
import './plugins/svg.resize/dist/svg.resize';
```

Comment: could you explain how you did this in the project more like the question structure, that was very useful, to get up and running with svg.js but I also want draggable as well, and I am unsure where to put everything now. using vue ui to install the library and plug in

Comment: @adamprocter what i did in question have to be discarded and you have to use what i have in answer. So drop everything from question, add imports from the answer and everything should work. Don't forget to use version < 3.0

Comment: Ok thanks will try was just not sure on all the steps

Answer (score 1):

I have my solution for working with non `npm`/`module` library.

First I will use [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) to serve file from directly from Github. For example `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg.js@2.7.1/dist/svg.min.js`.

Then I use [script.js](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) to load them.

```
script.order([
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg.js@2.7.1/dist/svg.min.js",
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg.select.js@3.0.1/dist/svg.select.min.js"
], () => {
  // window.SVG is available
});
```

[Live Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7146z5vy11)

Answer (score 1):

To use version 3.x you would either just do it with esm imports:

```
import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'
import '@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js'
// ...
```

No need to use plugins for vue. Just use `SVG()` in your code when you need it. If you need other functionality lile the "old" `SVG.on()` you need to import it, too: `import { SVG, on } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'`

Or you include it via script tags. svg.js always ships with prebundled files for that purpose:

```
<script src="node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/dist/svg.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js/dist/svg.draggable.js"></script>
```

You can just use the global `SVG` variable in that case and access everything with it like `SVG.on(...)`