# How to import thrid party js libraries in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Following is the code for using svg.js library in vue.js

I'm being able to use it's some plugins like draggable, panzoom, filter etc... (here are the plugins https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.1/plugins/)

Is there a way to use svg.path.js plugin?

```
import '@svgdotjs/svg.draggable.js';

import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js';


export default {
  name: 'svg',
  components: {},
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
  computed: {
  },
mounted() {
    var draw = SVG().addTo('body');
      draw
        .rect(150, 75)
        .move(100 , 50 )
        .radius(5)
}
}
```

Similarly is there a way for me to import `svg.path.js` in to vue js somehow and use it?

Here are some insights i found on stackoverflow:

[How do i use SVG.js plugins in vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588400/how-do-i-use-svg-js-plugins-in-vue-js#comment97874178_55588400)

this is that library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg.path.js

I've tried importing it this way:
`import 'svg.path.js'`

But I'm getting error `This dependency was not found:`

**NOTE**

Or is there a way to import js files directly in to vue.js?
**Please share.**

Comment: have u tried this way `import * as SVG from 'svg.js/dist/svg';` ?

Comment: Yes. I tried that way too.. But not sure how to use the plugins that come along with svg.js!!

Comment: Any hope ??????